# Help w/ memory management...allocations shows no leaks but program leaks like crazy

Tags: cocoa, memory-management

So I have autoreleased/released every object that I alloc/init/copy...and the allocations instrument seems to show minimal leaks...however...my program's memory usage does not stop increasing.  I have included a screenshot of my allocations run (I have run allocations for longer but it remains relatively constant...it certainly does not compare to the amount the program gains when actually running.  When running my program it will double in memory over the course of about 10 hours.  The memory drastically increases in the first 5 minutes however (2-3MB), and just keeps on going. I don't understand why allocations would remain constant when running in instruments but my program would just keep gaining memory when actually run.

Since I can't post images yet...here is the link to the screenshot:

[allocations run](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2636863/Screen%20shot%202010-11-25%20at%2012.22.10%20PM.png)

UPDATE: Here are some screenshots from my memory heapshot analysis...I am not allocating these objects explicitly and don't really know where they are coming from.  Almost all of them have their source with something similar to the second screenshot details on the right (lots of HTTPs and URLs in the call tree).  Anybody know where these are coming from?  I know I've read about some NSURLConnection leaks but I have tried all of the cache clearing that those suggest to no avail. Thanks for all the help so far!

[memory heap analysis 1](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2636863/SS1.png)

[memory heap analysis 2](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2636863/SS2.png)

Comment: What if you make the position of heapshot 1 your baseline and take your non-baseline heapshot some time after that? It looks pretty steady after that initial spike.

Comment: I have tried that and you are right the memory is relatively stable after that.  There are still smaller but similar leaks almost every heapshot though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Try heapshots.](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/)

Comment: Heapshots has been pretty helpful, however, I am unsure where most of these allocations are coming from...I am not making them explicitly... am going to edit my question w/ an update screenshot to see if anyone can help with that.  Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks again...heapshots was instrumental to solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running with different environment variables when you run in different environments?
For example, you could have NSZombie enabled when you launch your app (causing all your objects to not be free'd) but not when you run in Instruments?

Just for a sanity check - How are you determining memory usage? You say that memory usage keeps going up, but not when you run in Instruments. Given that Instruments is a reliable way of measuring memory usage (the most reliable way?) this sounds a little odd - a bit like saying memory keeps going up except when i try to measure it.

Comment: I am measuring my "actual" memory usage by looking at activity monitor when running my program (not from xcode).  After trying some  memory analysis in instruments, it appears that most of the leaks are from frameworks and not from my own allocations.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using autoreleased objects (like [NSString stringWithFormat:]) in a loop the pool won't be drained until that loop is exited and the program is allowed to complete the main event loop, at which point the autorelease pool is drained and a new one is instantiated.

If you have code like this the solution is to instantiate a new auto release pool before entering your loop, then draining it periodically during your loop (and reinstantiating the auto release pool after you drain it).

Comment: Are you draining them? My answer was just a guess, I'm not sure there's much we can do without seeing your code.

Comment: Yeah I am draining them.  My code is quite long, which is why I didn't post it.  Also, I forgot to mention that the leaks instrument reports no leaks.  Here is the gist of what my program does...maybe it will help.  The program runs on a timer (set to 30s for debugging purposes), when the timer fires, it calls some methods which make an NSURLConnection for an HTTP post, then parse the JSON data and do some stuff with the data.  Anyways...I guess my fundamental question is why would allocations and my actual program memory usage not match up?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know. Looking at what you've provided and what you've said (memory usage doubling in 10 hours) I would guess that the "leak" is very small, and if you're absolutely sure it's not in your code then it could possibly be in the framework you're using. I think if you post a long code sample StackOverflow will put it in a scrollable box so your question will still be readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Instruments** to find out the location of where your allocations are originating. When running **Instruments** in the **Allocation** mode:

- Move your mouse over the **Category** field in the **Object Summary**
- Click on the **Grey Circle with an arrow** which appears next to the field name

This will bring up a list of locations where the objects in that category have been instantiated from, and the stats of how many allocations each have made.

If your memory usage is rising (but not leaking) you should be able to see where that memory was created, and then track down why it is hanging around.

This tool is also very useful in reducing your memory profile for mobile applications.

Comment: @Peter: indeed. But I find myself worrying more about my memory profile on the former.